# Which ip address should I add in the SPF record for my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, spf, microsoft-office-365, txt-record

I own a domain eg. "mustang.com" and uses office365 for sending emails to my customers. My current `SPF` has below `TXT` records as described by Microsoft website

`v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all`

I currently use a third party software called Glockeasymail to send marketing campaigns and the email sending flow is like below

glock/software[ MyIP:111.90.148.45] ---> office365[ Lots of IP ? ]--> customers email

When looking at mail headers for emails sent by me , it involves multiple ip addresses, and **I want to know which IP addresses i need to add to my Domains SPF records besides the SPF recorded by microsoft. Do I have to add the IP addresses used by the glock software too ?**

Below is the mail header sent by me *(my email: dummyone@mustang.com)*
and received by my customer *johndoe@eagle.com*

```
Return-Path: <dummyone@mustang.com>
X-Original-To: johndoe@eagle.com
Delivered-To: johndoe@eagle.com
Received: from NAM02-BL2-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com (mail-bl2nam02on0110.outbound.protection.outlook.com [104.47.38.110])
        by server.eagle.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 51E58E0236A8
        for <johndoe@eagle.com>; Thu, 15 Jun 2017 13:00:41 +0800 (MYT)
Authentication-Results: server.eagle.com; dkim=pass
        reason="1024-bit key; unprotected key"
        header.d=eaglellc.onmicrosoft.com header.i=@eaglellc.onmicrosoft.com
        header.b=NBKZutko; dkim-adsp=none (unprotected policy);
        dkim-atps=neutral
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
     b=NBKZuJn2GopDhr1mAgBqsEayFfIwD4HgndnjZcciyL6W5KOZgGNMtMA=
Authentication-Results: eagle.com; dkim=none (message not signed)
     header.d=none;eagle.com; dmarc=none action=none
     header.from=mustang.com;
Received: from VPS45592 (111.90.148.45) by
     BLUPR17MB0452.namprd17.prod.outlook.com (10.164.17.30) with Microsoft SMTP
     Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256) id
     15.1.1157.12; Thu, 15 Jun 2017 05:00:37 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 15 Jun 2017 13:00:22 +0800
Message-ID: <89A62761DAA3060A1DFDAEB89E3C2B55383CE3A1@VPS45592>
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Subject: Your SMTP settings are correct
From: "dummyone" <dummyone@mustang.com>
Reply-To: "dummyone" <dummyone@mustang.com>
To: johndoe@eagle.com
X-Originating-IP: [111.90.148.45]
X-ClientProxiedBy: SG2PR01CA0047.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com (10.165.10.15)
     To BLUPR17MB0452.namprd17.prod.outlook.com (10.164.17.30)
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: BLUPR17MB0452:
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: dc4fa15a-4dcf-4111-293a-08d4b3ab76d1
X-Microsoft-Antispam:
```

Comment: yes you must include the spf or add the IP or any system that send email for your domain. GlockEasyMail shoud have a page that tell you what to add to your SPF, if not, ask them.

Answer (score 0):

If the Glockeasymail software is set up to send through Office365, then it will still be the Office365 servers that will be delivering the mail to the recipients, and hence the existing SPF record should be sufficient.

I assume that the Glockeasymail software delivers the mail to Office365 using SMTP with username and password, and this is the same as if the mail was sent with a normal mail-client (which does not require modified SPF records).